# Howto write a class where a property can be accessed without naming it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class-design

I have a (dump) question regarding VB/C#

I often use third party classes where I can access a child object with only specifying the id or key.

Example:

Instead of writing:

```
DataRow row = GetAPopulatedDataRowSomeWhere();
Object result = row.Items[1]; // DataRow has no Items property
Object result = row.Items["colName"]; // Also not possible
```

I use this code to access the members:

```
DataRow row = GetAPopulatedDataRowSomeWhere();
Object result = row[1];
Object result = row["colName"];
```

Can someone tell me how a class has to look like to support this syntax?
My own class has a Dictionary that I want to access this way.

```
MyClass["key"]; // <- that's what I want
MyClass.SubItems["key"]; // <- that's how I use it now
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to have an [indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(VS.71).aspx).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return SubItems[key]; }
        set { SubItems[key] = value; }
    }
}
```